# setting many objects in session attribute --is it okay?

Tags: java, dictionary

i am creating some Map objects and some set objects in my java action class and getting those values in the next servlet / jsps . Is this the good approach i am following is there any other way better than this ...i am storing these values in one of the action class and using them in another. I am doing this to prevent the loading time in the next class , also for some minor reasons.....

```
 SessionUtils.setNamespacedAttribute(session, "mapofAllexistingservers", null, mapofallservers);
            SessionUtils.setNamespacedAttribute(session, "mapOriginal", null, mapRight);
            SessionUtils.setNamespacedAttribute(session, "mapleft", null, mapLeft);
            SessionUtils.setNamespacedAttribute(session, "CancelProducts", null, "Cancel");
            SessionUtils.setNamespacedAttribute(session, "networkCollect", null, treeMapNetworks);
            SessionUtils.setNamespacedAttribute(session, "setOfSharedServers", null, setOfSharedServers);
```

Comment: You've been somewhat vague here, and this seems to be a design decision. To me, if it's necessary than it's necessary. What benefits have you seen from this? What cons have you seen?

Answer (score 1):

This is not so clean but its okay. Maybe you can wrap all the map*-attributes into a new Object (dont forget the serialize-interface).

If you passivate the session, the `setOfsharedServers` may defunc because the shared servers are not available after activation of the session any more.

Answer (score 1):

In general practice, adding a lot of data to `HttpSession` implementations is mostly OK. The difference between a few KB is negligible at the user level nowadays. You should start being a little bit more stingy when it comes to larger, distributed enterprise applications. Especially in the case where you are deploying on multiple application servers, it will eventually become in your best interest to support high-availability clustering and load-balancing across the servers. In order to achieve this, some third party (`Infinispan` and `JGroups`) must be made responsible for session replication. This multiplies your session object size many times and adds a fairly serious memory and network overhead. It'll be at this time that you wish your session was minimal.

Comment: Thanks Kon... one question on this --- if i am using session in my class files and  i am using clustered servers in prod ( two servers ) , than i have to deploy my jar file in both the servers ....So now when user will access the application it can be accessed by either server so at that time Does clustering can effect any thing on user session , can clustering conflict the session of the user vlaues ?